# Is there a way to gather the SSIDs of the connected networks in the background?

Tags: swift, background, wifi, nehotspothelper

I'm trying to build a Swift application that saves the SSIDs and the time of connection to all networks encountered throughout the day (obviously, networks to which I already have access). The problem is that my application only works in the foreground, and I have no idea how to make it work in the background, if possible. Currently, I'm using NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent().

I've already tried using Background Tasks, but without success.

Comment: You could possibly do it via "always" background location updates, gathering the connected wifi name each time you got a location update but it would be expensive in terms of battery.